# Blank character issue in JSP template

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following markup in a JSP:

```
<div class="row teaser-module ${module.cssClass} ${module.isNarrow ? 'narrow' : 'regular'}">
```

I did some tests on several servers. Some of them render the expected output, which is:

```
<div class="row teaser-module one-item narrow">
```

But on another server, the blank space is removed between the 2 classes:

```
<div class="row teaser-module one-itemnarrow">
```

Is there any rational reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know JSP really and can't think of a reason for that to happen, but you could try adding a space to the ' narrow' and ' regular' strings to force the space to be present that way.

```
<div class="row teaser-module ${module.cssClass} ${module.isNarrow ? ' narrow' : ' regular'}">
```

Comment: I'll try that, and let you know